# What happened to Turner Bikes?

Tags: mountain-bike, titanium

I could be misremembering this but back in ~2014 turner bikes made a bunch of really high quality full suspension mountain (and other) bikes in the US. I just decided to look them up today and they only have two bikes, neither made in the US, and both looking quite limited (a no suspension gravel bike and a hard tail). Many sections of their site return errors as well, and their Wikipedia page stops talking about new releases after ~2010

Is the brand dead? Were they sold off? What happened?

Answer (score 4):

The [link in this 2012 article on Turner bikes](https://www.bikeradar.com/reviews/bikes/mountain-bikes/turner-5-spot-review/) to the makers website points to [turnerbikes.com](https://turnerbikes.com/)
I don't see anything but hard tails there

An [article in Bicycle Retailer](https://www.bicycleretailer.com/product-tech/2021/03/15/turner-bikes-turns-titanium) says

> Hardtail, gravel and all-road models represent major shift from full-suspension.
> A version of this article ran in the March issue of BRAIN.
>
> MURRIETA, Calif. (BRAIN) — After “chasing the carbon dream” the past decade, Dave Turner said it’s time to return to his cycling roots. That means turning to titanium frame production and away — at least temporarily — from full-suspension production.

So, I think this is the Turner of which you speak.

Comment: If you look at this archive page from 2014 you can see a full range of bikes from DH and enduro to XC, and interestingly no hardtails (although I'm sure they had them at one point or another). Also interestingly I was speaking to one of my family members who has an old Turner and apparently their aluminum supplier in Oregon got really outdated (maybe went under?) which was likely part of it, but I have no good sources for that

Comment: whoops forgot the link https://web.archive.org/web/20140208045122/https://turnerbikes.com/